# listbox.SetSelected(int, true) is not working in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7 app, I have a listbox in the Xaml with some stuff in it.

Then in the C# code, I tried

```
listbox.SetSelected( anInteger, true);
```

Only it didn't work.

So am I doing something wrong? How do I select an item from the listbox with an integer in Windows Phone 7 with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28VS.95%29.aspx) Class Methods, you will notice that the [SetSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx) method is not supported for WP7.

Try using the SelectedIndex property instead:

```
private void btnSetSelected_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.listBox.SelectedIndex = anInteger;
}
```

This article could be pretty useful: [Working with WP7 ListBox SelectedItem](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/WP7-ListBox-SelectedItem)

Comment: Thanks! I'll get round to checking this in a few hours. Can't get to my code yet...